# WAB Authentication failed

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I tried to make a really simple application, using the [active-directory-dotnet-native-uwp-v2](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-uwp-v2) sample.

With my MSA Account, it works correctly, but with my corporate account, it doesn't work as expected (I used a **@microsoft.com** account)

This account is a Office 365 account, and actually it works pretty fine in the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) for instance.

**The problem is that sometimes, it works ...**

My manifest file declared in https://apps.dev.microsoft.com is correctly configured, with a **Native Platform** option, and "just" a `"User.Read"` scope autorisation

The code is pretty straightforward, here is the extract from the sample :

```
AuthenticationResult authResult = null;

    try
    {
        authResult = await App.PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(scopes, App.PublicClientApp.Users.FirstOrDefault());
}
    catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
    {
        // A MsalUiRequiredException happened on AcquireTokenSilentAsync. This indicates you need to call AcquireTokenAsync to acquire a token
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"MsalUiRequiredException: {ex.Message}");

        try
        {
            authResult = await App.PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync(scopes);
}
        catch (MsalException msalex)
        {
            ResultText.Text = $"Error Acquiring Token:{System.Environment.NewLine}{msalex}";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ResultText.Text = $"Error Acquiring Token Silently:{System.Environment.NewLine}{ex}";
        return;
    }
```

Once launched, I can set my account, but the redirection is broken.

[image: First step. Set my account]

[image: Second step. error is throw]

From what i can see, i have an **Msal Exception** :

`authentication_ui_failed`

If i check deeper the call stack, the only thing i found is :

`active_directory_dotnet_native_uwp_v2.MainPage.<CallGraphButton_Click>d__3.MoveNext()`

Any idea ?

Comment: To narrow down this issue, I suggest that you trying to capture the detailed error message from the HTTP response using the Fiddler.

Comment: The MSAL authentication process does not work when filddler is running.
Any tips to make it works ?

Comment: What kind of error did you get? There are some similar issue relative to `authentication_ui_failed`, is it helpful for this issue? Refer [issue1](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/222) and [issue2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31755699/acquiretokenasync-fails-in-a-uwp-app).

Comment: Actually, I activated the "private networks" capability and it seems to works now. Thx for your references !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned you figured out how to solve this problem, so I will add some additional context: In general you do not need to add *privateNetworkClientServer* to UWP apps only to authenticate against AD **IF** you only need to access your application outside of your company's premises (or in some cases VPN environment).

However, in some cases - if your device is actually connected to your corporate network, then Windows will try to use things like integrated auth to help sign-in users with less effort. In this case, it is recommended to declare this as a capability so your app can run anywhere.